# Haar measure and Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, haar-measure

So in my textbook i get this expression that i just quite dont understand.
Let $G$ be a compact group, and $\mu$ the normalised Haar measure on G. Let $(\pi, \mathcal H)$ Be a unitary representation of $G$. For $v \in \mathcal H$ cosider the operator $K_v$ of $\mathcal H$
$$ K_vw = \int_G (w | \pi(g)v)\ \pi(g)v \ \mu(dg) $$
Here $(\cdot| \cdot)$  is an innerproduct. So the book says this also can be written as
$$ (K_vw | w' )  = \int_G (w|\pi(g)v)\overline{(w'|\pi(g)v)} \mu(dg)$$

I just dont see how these two are the same? The first $K_vw$ isn't it an operator from $\mathcal H \to \mathbb{C}?$ and the second one needs to take to inputs, a $w$ and a $w'$??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $K_w$ is not an operator from $\mathcal H$ into $\Bbb C$. It's from $\mathcal H$ into $\mathcal H$. Note that each $\bigl(w\mid \pi(g)v\bigr)\pi(g)v$ is an element of $\mathcal H$.

Knowing a vector $v$ is the same thing as knowing the map $(v\mid\cdot)$. So, knowing the vector $K_vw$ is the same thing as knowing the value of $\left(K_vw\mid w'\right)$ for every vector $w'$. And it turns out that$$\left(K_vw\mid w'\right)=\int_G\bigl(w\mid\pi(g)v\bigr)\overline{\bigl(w'\mid\pi(g)v\bigr)}\,\mu(dg).$$

Comment: Ah, yea, of course it is an map from $\mathcal H \to \mathcal H$. 
I am not quite sure what you mean that knowing the vector $v$ is the same thing as knowing the map $(v|\cdot)$??

Comment: I mean that the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathcal H&\longrightarrow&\mathcal H^*\\v&\mapsto&(v\mid\cdot)\end{array}$$is a bijection. In particular, if $v\in\mathcal H$, there is no other vector $v'\ne v$ such that$$(\forall w\in\mathcal H):(v\mid w)=(v'\mid w).$$

Comment: Makes sense thanks! Just last question ;) You say knowing the vector $K_vw$ is the same thing as knowing the value of $(K_vw|w')$, but why is $K_vw$ a vector? i get that the $(w|\pi(g)v)\pi(g)v$ is a vector, but the whole integral is a value just like $(K_vw | w')$ right??

Comment: No. If you integrate vectors, then you get vectors. For instance$$\int_0^1(t,t^2)\,\mathrm dt=\left(\frac12,\frac13\right).$$

Comment: I dont know why i dont get it again. So i just cant figure out why it turns out that the inner product $(K_vw | w')$ is equal to that integral ?? I am trying to write it out, but i dont feel like it gets me anywhere?

Comment: \begin{align}(K_vw\mid w')&=\left(\int_G\bigl(w\mid\pi(g)v\bigr)\pi(g)v\,\mu(\mathrm dg)\,\middle|\,w'\right)\\&=\int_G\left(\bigl(w\mid\pi(g)v\bigr)\pi(g)v\mid w'\right)\,\mu(\mathrm dg)\\&=\int_G\bigl(w\mid\pi(g)v\bigr)\bigl(\pi(g)v\mid w'\bigr)\,\mu(\mathrm dg)\\&=\int_G\bigl(w\mid\pi(g)v\bigr)\overline{\bigl(w'\mid\pi(g)v\bigr)}\,\mu(\mathrm dg).\end{align}